# How to center hat in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

How to center hat in math mode?

```
\begin{equation}
    \hat{I}(x) 
\end{equation}
```

[image]

I tried mathrel, which does not help.

```
\begin{equation}
    \mathrel{\hat{I}}(x) 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Why do you think `\mathrel` would help here?

Comment: Please _always_ include a complete small test document that shows the problem. The standard result is not as you show, I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS9KN.png) from `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\hat{I}\end{equation}
\end{document}` so the problem is with code you have not shown.